# assertText a message that has line break in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium

I am new in Selenium IDE and need to assertText a value that has line break. Example:

Actual Message to assertText:
Hello
World

```
store      | Hello <br/> World | txtValue
assertText | id=label          | ${txtValue}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Pass your `id=label` into a variable, remove the line breaks, then run an assertion against the variable.

1. Store expected text:

   ```
   store | Hello World | txtValue
   ```
2. Store page text:

   ```
   storeText | xpath=(//*[@id=label]) | labelValue
   ```
3. Remove line breaks from page text:

   ```
   echo  | javascript{storedVars.labelValue = storedVars.labelValue.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"")} |
   ```
4. Assert your expected text = your page text:

   ```
   assertExpression | javascript{storedVars.txtValue==storedVars.labelValue} | true
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Following pattern matching worked for me on `Selenium IDE 2.5.0`

```
regexp:Hello\s+World
```